# Почему у меня не подключается собственный плагин?

Tags: jquery

Я создал плагин
js/AnimatedForm/animated-form.js

```js
 (function( $ ){
        $.fn.animatedForm = function () {
            return this.html(`<div class="sa">
                <div class="sa-success">
                     <div class="sa-success-tip"></div>
                     <div class="sa-success-long"></div>
                     <div class="sa-success-placeholder"></div>
                     <div class="sa-success-fix"></div>
                </div>
    </div>`)
        }
    })( JQuery );
```

И стили в плагине js/AnimatedForm/css/animated-form.css, но принципе не важно что там написано
В index.html я прописал

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/AnimateFrom/css/animate-form.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="focus_form-message"></div>
<button type="submit" class="focus_form-button">Записаться</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="resource/js/form.js"></script>
    <script src="js/AnimateFrom/animate-form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

В файле resource/js/form.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#focus_form_recording').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post({
            ...
        })
            .done(request => {
...
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.focus_form-message').animatedForm();
                        // $('.focus_form-button').html(`Записаться`);
                    }, 500);
                }
                console.log(res);
            })
            .fail(err => console.error(err))
    })
});
```

Но получаю ответ

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).animatedForm is not a function
```

Ссылка на гитхаб https://github.com/rusline18/latina

Comment: animated-form.js и form.js местами поменяйте при подключении

Comment: Не помогло, говорит что Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined. Это вначале, но вроде бы она стоит ниже Jquery

Comment: Ошибка в опечатке - пожалуйста, удалите свой вопрос.

Comment: Я не могу удалить свой вопрос, пишет что разработчики потратили свое время и поэтому нельзя удалить его

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в синтаксисе, `jQuery` надо сделать а не `JQuery`

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.animatedForm = function () {
        return this.html(`<div class="sa">
            <div class="sa-success">
                 <div class="sa-success-tip"></div>
                 <div class="sa-success-long"></div>
                 <div class="sa-success-placeholder"></div>
                 <div class="sa-success-fix"></div>
            </div>
            </div>`)
    }
})( jQuery ); // <- Тут заменить JQuery на jQuery
```

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin как бы это ответ. В коде реально эта проблема.

Comment: А какая проблема? У меня стало работать